# Does JLex include a yymore function?

Tags: java, lexer

Lex includes a function `yymore()` that concatenates the next recognized input expression to the current input string.

JLex, which implements Lex for Java (and is not the same package as jflex, to my knowledge), does not mention `yymore()` in its [documentation](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/JLex/current/manual.html). Does  `yymore()` work in JLex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

From a Coursera forum (this was also my experience):

> The middle of section 4 of the Lex manual shows the use of a yymore() method to ease parsing of string literals. This method does not seem to be available in JLex.

https://class.coursera.org/compilers-003/forum/thread?thread_id=223, Tim McIver